# Combinations Question with Paths

Tags: statistics, combinations

I encountered this question in an online course (Stat 110 from Harvard), and even with the explanation I can't intuitively figure out how this works. Could someone please provide an intuitive explanation

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: what direct questions do you have about it ? we figured out the number of ways to place the R's in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ball and urn problem.

Imagine that you place $221$ balls in an urn. On $110$ of the balls is the letter $\mathbf{U}$ for "up" and on $111$ of the balls is the letter $\mathbf{R}$ for "right."

You draw all the balls out of the urn which will instruct you along one of the possible paths from $(0,0)$ to $(110,111)$.

The number of possible paths would then equal the number of possible ways you could pick $110$ (or equivalently $111$) of the balls out of the urn.